# C# - Использования одной формы для передачи в другие две

Tags: c#, winforms, передача-данных

**День добрый! Опять обращаюсь с бональщиной.**

У меня есть проект на C# связанный с автосервисом. Так-как я по максимуму пытаюсь минимизировать проект в плане WindowsForm, **я пришел к следующему вопросу:**

Как мне использовать одну форму с "Добавить клиента", в двух разных вызываемых формах.

**К примеру:**

У меня есть форма с "Добавить акт" и "Обновить акт". Как форме "Добавить клиента" понять, в какую из форм ей надо вернуться с значение выбранным из DataGridView с формы выбора клиента.

Пытался сделать просто костыль с проверкой формы по передаваемой ей строке с разными значениями:

**public string form = "Форма: Добавить" (Означало бы форме "Добавить клиента", что именно из формы "Добавить акт" к ней обращаются)**, сделал принимаемую строку public string forma в форме "Добавить клиента" и уже из нее, что я выбераю, я сравниваю значение с переменной forma
и если она равна "Форма: Добавить", то переменная с int id уходит на форму "Добавить акт", а если значение было бы "Форма: Обновить", то он ушел на форму "Обновить акт".

Код прикреплен снизу, какие строки и как задействуються:

**Форма "Добавить акт":**

```
public string form = "Форма: Добавить";

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Выбор клиента

   AddClient AC = new AddClient();
   AC.forma = form;
   AC.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Форма "Обновить акт":**

```
public int id_client;

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Выбор клиента

   AddClient AC = new AddClient();
   AC.forma = form;
   AC.ShowDialog();
}
```

**Форма "Добавить клиента":**

```
public string forma;
public int id;

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (forma == "Форма: Добавить")
      {
      AddAccept AA = new AddAccept();
      AA.id_client = id;
      this.Hide();
   }
   else if (forma == "Форма: Обновить")
   {
      AboutAccept ABA = new AboutAccept();
      ABA.id_client = id;
      this.Hide();
   } 
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   int row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

   id = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value;
}
```

Comment: Остальные данные, как я надеюсь не нужны, так-как другая часть сугубо направлена на то, чтобы эти данные добавить в СУБД SQL, да и сама задача у меня стоит в одном, использовать одну форму из других двух не прибегая к созданию еще двух аналогичных форм, только с другим переходом.

Comment: А что вам мешает вместо строки в поле forma передавать экземпляр класса с нужным действием (AddAccept или AboutAccept)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это же очевидно, Ватсон! Вернуться придётся туда, откуда форма была вызана, других вариантов нет.

Очевидно, что форма "Добавить клиента" должна быть модальная, т. е. пока не выберешь клиента или не отменишь, ничего другого делать не можешь. Соответственно, возврат произойдёт к месту, откуда она была запущена.

```
AddClient AC = new AddClient();
AC.forma = form;
AC.ShowDialog();
// сюда попадём после закрытия "Добавить клиента"
// забрать из "Добавить клиента" результат
```

Не нужно делать всё шиворот на выворот. Не "Добавить клиента" должна искать, куда бы ей засунуть выходное значение, а запустившая её форма должна сама забрать это значение из "Добавить клиента".